# Efficient way to write SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I have a table that is populated by complex SQL in stored procedure.  I'm thinking to write UPDATE statement on BILL_ADJ_MSG after it is populated, as I do not want to manipulate the existing complex logic.
The requirement is to suppress message codes '161' and '162' if any other message code exists.  However, keep '161' and '162' message code of no other message code exists.
suppressing message would mean replace '161' OR '162' with ' '

Here is the example of existing sample data in BILL_ADJ_MSG :

```
B_NO    MSG_1   MSG_2   MSG_3   MSG_4
----------------------------------------
100     UA1     16       15      162
200     161     UA161           
300     162
400     161     162
```

Desired Output after update in in BILL_ADJ_MSG:

```
B_NO    MSG_1       MSG_2       MSG_3       MSG_4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
100     UA1         16              15      
200                 UA161                       
300     162     
400     161         162
```

Any idea how to accomplish in most optimized way?  I'm looking to update more about 2 millioin records

So far, I'm trying to work with UPDATE sql with CASE statement

```
UPDATE BILL_ADJ_MSG
SET MSG_1 = 
CASE
WHEN MSG_1 IN ('161','162')
THEN ' '
ELSE MSG_1
END,
---SAME FOR MSG_2, MSG_3, MSG_4 --
WHERE 
TRIM(MSG_1)||TRIM(MSG_2)||TRIM(MSG_3)||TRIM(MSG_4) NOT IN ('161162','162161', '161','162');
```

Comment: and what is your problem?

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Don't try to do this. It is far, far more efficient to populate a column at insert time than to update it later. I realize the SQL may be intimidating to think of modifying, but that is the correct way to do this. Don't patch it with a later update or you will most certainly create a performance issue. Updates create massive undo, potential row chaining, decompression, etc... lots of bad stuff at those volumes. You can probably simplify the changes to the existing insert by wrapping the query portion in a CTE (with clause) and adding your own subsequent, main block that can reference the CTE.

Comment: Are all error codes 3 digit?

Answer (score 2):

You want something like:

```sql
UPDATE BILL_ADJ_MSG
SET   MSG_1 = CASE WHEN MSG_1 NOT IN ('161','162') THEN msg_1 ELSE ' ' END,
      MSG_2 = CASE WHEN MSG_2 NOT IN ('161','162') THEN msg_2 ELSE ' ' END,
      MSG_3 = CASE WHEN MSG_3 NOT IN ('161','162') THEN msg_3 ELSE ' ' END,
      MSG_4 = CASE WHEN MSG_4 NOT IN ('161','162') THEN msg_4 ELSE ' ' END
WHERE ( msg_1 IN ('161','162') AND (  msg_2 NOT IN ('161','162') 
                                   OR msg_3 NOT IN ('161','162') 
                                   OR msg_4 NOT IN ('161','162') ) )
OR    ( msg_2 IN ('161','162') AND (  msg_1 NOT IN ('161','162') 
                                   OR msg_3 NOT IN ('161','162') 
                                   OR msg_4 NOT IN ('161','162') ) )
OR    ( msg_3 IN ('161','162') AND (  msg_1 NOT IN ('161','162') 
                                   OR msg_2 NOT IN ('161','162') 
                                   OR msg_4 NOT IN ('161','162') ) )
OR    ( msg_4 IN ('161','162') AND (  msg_1 NOT IN ('161','162') 
                                   OR msg_2 NOT IN ('161','162') 
                                   OR msg_3 NOT IN ('161','162') ) );
```

You may need to add additional checks if your columns can be `NULL`

Comment: Looks fine to me. There can be nulls - at least this is how I read the sample data - but they don't affect the correctness of the update statement.